# Converting CSV to CLF in Python

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I get a TypeError "TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index".

I'm not quite sure why and I can't find anything to explain why I'm getting that error. Can somebody please explain what I'm doing wrong and suggest a way to correct it?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

data1 = np.loadtxt('0003_1.csv', delimiter=",")

indices = np.random.permutation(len(data1.data))

split = round(len(indices) * 0.8)
x_train = data1.data[indices[:split]]
y_train = data1.target[indices[:split]]
x_test = data1.data[indices[split:]]
y_test = data1.target[indices[split:]]


clf = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(100, 100, 100), max_iter=500, alpha=0.0001, solver='sgd', verbose=10, random_state=21, tol=0.000000001)
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(x_test)
accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
```

Comment: What line is producing the error?  What is `data1.data` supposed to be?  `data1.target`?

Comment: @hp x_train = data1.data[indices[:split]] is where the error occurs. data is the data and target is the target in terms of machine learning.
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/59149-what-are-target-variables-predictor-variables-and-prior-probabilities

Answer (score 0):

Is it fair to assume that you did not try this code line by line, looking at the results along the way?

You didn't provide the `csv` file, but `loadtxt` called that way can only produce a 2d array of floats, so lets simulate that with `np.ones`:

```
In [637]: data1 = np.ones((10,10))
```

Such an array does have a `data` attribute, which is a `memoryview`:

```
In [638]: data1.data
Out[638]: <memory at 0x7fc5b6916c18>
```

It does not have a `target` attribute.  Your `csv` may have columns with names like this (but you did not read a header), but this `loadtxt` did not load them that way.

```
In [639]: data1.target
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-639-43b9ce1927aa> in <module>()
----> 1 data1.target

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'target'
```

But let's work forward to your error. `.data` has a `len` just like `data1`, so `indices` works:

```
In [640]: indices = np.random.permutation(len(data1.data))
In [641]: indices
Out[641]: array([0, 7, 6, 4, 8, 5, 2, 1, 9, 3])
In [642]: split = round(len(indices) * 0.8)
In [643]: split
Out[643]: 8
In [644]: indices[:split]
Out[644]: array([0, 7, 6, 4, 8, 5, 2, 1])
```

But a `memoryview` cannot be indexed with a slice:

```
In [645]: data1.data[indices[:split]]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-645-b6cf2f74578c> in <module>()
----> 1 data1.data[indices[:split]]

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

The 2d array can be indexed with this slice:

```
In [646]: data1[indices[:split]]
Out[646]: 
array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

So the root of the problem is thinking that `data1.data` and `data1.target` are useful expressions.  In effect you did not load the data object that you expected, or in a way that you expected.  And you did not check `data1`.